# Como hacer click o activar un Switch Button de un recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Pasa que tengo un recycler view con un switch button (ademas ya carga un alista de items de base de datos con mysql,php etc), y quiero desde un activity obtener la el ID del elemento, cuando accione el boton switch, adjunto estas capturas para hacerme entender mejor, Que para que quiero el id ? para agregarle ese id_item al usuario q esta logueado, (almacene los datos del usuario en sqlite ) asi q solo consulto el helperdb para obtener el id de usuario y asi poder enviar esos 2 ID a un api, Me podrian orientar por favor ?? me seria de gran ayuda su colaboracion.

[image: Adaptador]
[image: Clase]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, acostumbra agregar el código como texto y no como imagen, revisa también, [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien para hacer lo que necesitas puedes crear una interface en el adapter, pasarla por el contructor, y en la misma regresas el ID que te interesa, en el caso que planteas puede ser de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Trends_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Trends_Adapter.ViewHolder>{

private EventListener eventlistener;

public interface EventListener{
    void onItemSelected(String ID);
}

public Trends_Adapter(....., ......, ....., ......, EventListener eventlistener) {
        ......
        ......
        this.eventListener = eventListener;
    }

//.............
.........
......//
}
```

Dentro del `onBindViewHolder` donde utilizas el `switch` haces lo siguiente:

```
holder.sw_active.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // Si esta activo.
            String id = list_data.get(rv.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getId_pa());
            eventlistener.onItemSelected(id);
        } else {
            // Si no esta activo
        }
    }
});
```

Bien ahora vas a la clase donde haces uso del `adapter` e implementas esta `interface`, de esta manera:

```
public class CLASS_NAME extends AppCompactActivity implements Trends_Adapter.EventListener{

private Trends_Adapter trendsadapter;
......

onCreate{

.....
.....
.....

trendsadapter = new Trends_Adapter(...., ...., ...., this);
// allí estas diciendo que el EventListener se ejecutara aquí
}


@Override
public void EventListener(String id){
// Acá dentro estar recibiendo el método de la interface definido en el adapter
// Ese id que esta llegando es el enviado por el método según la posición
// Desde aquí puedes hacer lo que necesitas hacer con este id que ya tienes

    }
}
```

La idea es esta, cada vez que necesites algo del adapter, sea el Id, la posición, un nombre, puedes hacerlo de esta forma, y así trabajarlo mucho mas sencillo.

Comment: Te estoy dando la idea de como resolver tu problema, y si se ve un poco desorganizado es debido a que publicaste tu duda por imágenes y no por código directamente como te comento @Elenasys